# Building Lua library lpack in windows 10 '%1 is not a valid Win32 application.'

Tags: windows, command-line, lua

Using the instructions from [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Br8l4Z_XUgoC&pg=PA385&lpg=PA385&dq=lua%20pack.dll&source=bl&ots=DiCnj7TvmK&sig=PkRNGCHn-z_zpgqVy3X-Lm7rIJ8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib3ui2gIXaAhVEPhQKHQ5lAl0Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=lua%20pack.dll&f=false). Updated because of depreciated options for cl.exe leaves me with the error

```
lua: error loading module 'pack' from file './pack.dll':
        %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

When I get to testing the compiled pack.dll

Full command line readout as follows:

```
C:\luawin\lpack-master\pack>cl /c /W1 /Zl /Zi /MD /DWIN32 lpack.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.13.26129 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

lpack.c


C:\luawin\lpack-master\pack>link /dll /out:pack.dll /base:0x67400000 
/machine:ix86 /export:luaopen_pack lpack.obj lua5.3.lib msvcrt.lib
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.13.26129.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Creating library pack.lib and object pack.exp


C:\luawin\lpack-master\pack>lua -e "package.cpath='./?.dll' require 
'pack' print(string.pack('b3', 76, 117, 97))"
lua: error loading module 'pack' from file './pack.dll':
    %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

stack traceback:
    [C]: in ?
    [C]: in function 'require'
    (command line):1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Some sort of architecture option issue I presume.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49465602/edit) to include more information if commenters ask you to.  Is it perhaps a 32/64-bit mismatch issue?  What if you remove `/base` and `/machine` from the `link` command line?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion cxw, exactly the same result however.

Comment: Cannot believe that it would even compile - you must specify Lua include path and Lua library to link